# Is there support of hmac-md5-96 in setkey ipsec tools?

Tags: ipsec

I want to use "hmac-md5-96" algorithm to create Security Associations at client side. I am using setkey ipsec tools. while adding spd entry, It is giving syntax error and unable to identify hmac-md5-96

I have tried keyed-md5 which is also not supported.

```
setkey -c << EOF
add $pcscf $ue esp $spi_uc -m transport -E aes-cbc $ck -A  hmac-md5-96 "1234567890123456" ;
spdadd $pcscf/32[$port_ps] $ue/32[$port_uc] tcp -P in ipsec esp/transport//require ;
spdadd $pcscf/32[$port_ps] $ue/32[$port_uc] udp -P in ipsec esp/transport//require ;
EOF
```

Comment: Giving an exact copy of the error would help us help you.  Additionally, platform, environment and installation details may also help re-produce the problem.

Comment: Can't you use `ip xfrm` instead? It is possible to specify truncation length with `auth-trunc` here...Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ip xfrm state add` instead of `setkey`, i.e.:

`ip xfrm state add src $pcscf dst $ue proto esp spi $spi_uc enc "cbc(aes)" $ck auth-trunc "hmac(md5)" "1234567890123456" 96 mode transport`

For some dummy parameters it creates the following SAD entry:

```
src 11.22.33.44 dst 22.33.44.55
        proto esp spi 0x00000457 reqid 0 mode transport
        replay-window 0 
        auth-trunc hmac(md5) 0x31323334353637383930313233343536 96
        enc cbc(aes) 0x3131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
        sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
```

Good luck!

Comment: ip xfrm state add src 192.168.139.37 dst 192.168.103.174 proto esp spi  1111 enc "cbc(aes)" "1234567891234567" auth-trunc "hmac(md5)" "1234567890123456" 96 mode trasnport

It is giving error. argument "auth-trunc" is wrong: unknown

Comment: ip xfrm is not able to identify auth-trunc. May be version issue.